# Resize image with gd on upload

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to resize a image on upload but i get this error in return.
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(myimage.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. Why doesn't my code work? and what can i do to make it work?

```
//Input values
$image = htmlspecialchars($_FILES['image']['name']);

// image file type
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$imageFileType = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

switch ($imageFileType) {
    case 'jpg':
        $image_create = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
        $image_save = 'imagejpeg';
        $new_image_ext = 'jpg';
        break;
    case 'jpeg':
        $image_create = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
        $image_save = 'imagejpeg';
        $new_image_ext = 'jpeg';
        break;
    case 'png':
        $image_create = 'imagecreatefrompng';
        $image_save = 'imagepng';
        $new_image_ext = 'png';
        break;
    default:
        echo "use a image";
}

$img_format = $image_create($image);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);

// new height and width
$newHeight = 150;
$newWidth = 150;

// create new image with new width and height
$destination = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($destination, $img_format, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG files are allowed.";
} else {
    if($image_save($destination, "images/".$uploadedfile.".".$new_image_ext, 100)){
        $sql = "UPDATE home SET image='$image' WHERE images_id=1";
        echo "Succes";
    } else{
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the image doesn't exist yet in that form.  You need to get it into the filesystem first, with move_uploaded_file().

Comment: hmm, i see is there a way to resize it before uploading it to my filesystem?

Comment: If you could somehow access it in the tmp location, *maybe*.  Otherwise take the upload, move it, resize it, and delete the original, I think, is the only way?

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey Okay thanks, i will try this out!